# Making PGMs negative

Tags: c++, vector, flip, pgm

I'm a bit lost as to how I would take a pgm file stored into a vector and flip the order of the cells so as to make the final image a negative flip.  I don't want the answer handed to me, I would just like some tips in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "negative flip" - Do you mean horizontal? vertical? or inverting the values?

Comment: Binary or text pgm format?  If you're parsing text, just loop backwards through the bitmap array (you will still be reading forwards through the file).

Comment: Text format.  And I mean by taking the lightest values and making them the darkest and vice versa.  Like a negative film.

Comment: @user3250013 In that case, since your pixel values are likely in the range 0-255, wouldn't simply making your output pixel be `255-input` be what you're looking for?